# How to correct exception when registering user entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, usermanager

I am trying to add roles to my default mvc6 project. I am getting a exception in my
 register.cshtml

```
@model TransparentEnergy.Models.RegisterViewModel

<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
          <h2>Register New User</h2>
      </div>
       <div class="card-body card-padding">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
           {
              @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="card-body card-padding">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="fg-line">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control fg-input" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <div class="fg-line">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control fg-input" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ConfirmPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                        <div class="fg-line">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control fg-input" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Role Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="fg-line select">
                                @Html.DropDownList("Name", null, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Register</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        }

        @section Scripts {
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

Error Message is

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Name' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

AccountController

```
   // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                //Assign Role to user Here 
                await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);
                //Ends Here


                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

RegisterViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't create a dropdownlist for a string property, it must be of type IEnumerable. It's *literally* in the exception text you've inserted. What are you trying to do? What result are you expecting?

Comment: thing is i following a example which appears to work for many ppl. I am trying to implement user roles. When i register a user i want a select box of roles to choose from. the selectbox is diplaying them but error comes on submit. here is example

Comment: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1102/aspnet-mvc-role-based-security

Comment: Is that your entire view?

Comment: just updated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
[Required]
[EmailAddress]
[Display(Name = "Email")]
public string Email { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
public string FullName { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Role")]
public string Name { get; set; }

//store roles
public IEnumerable<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}
```

Your GET controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel();
    //Controller should not intervene with presentation logic
    //so SelectList is not used here
    model.Roles = context.Roles.ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

Finally your View, change:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name", null, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker"})
```

To:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, 
          new SelectList(Model.Roles, "Name", "Name"), 
          new { @class = "form-control selectpicker"})
```

Update:
Your POST controller:

```
  model.Roles = context.Roles.ToList();
  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
   return View(model);
```

Comment: Line 46:    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name,

Comment: This error occurred when validation of data failed right? E.g. when email is blank and you click the register button. If it is the case, you need to populate the roles again in the post controller before returning the view

Comment: Update is made in the answer.